# Unable to deploy Trigger.io solution real device when parse.com option is enabled

Tags: trigger.io, parse-platform

I want to use parse.com push notifications in my Trigger.io solution, however, when I enable the partners parse.com option and opt to deploy to my iPhone (real device), I get the following error:

```
[ 48%] Copying /Users/Brady/forge-workspace/rj/development/ios/device-ios.app//retina.png to device
[ 49%] Copying /Users/Brady/forge-workspace/rj/development/ios/device-ios.app//tabs_modalWebViewController.nib to device
[ 50%] TakingInstallLock
[ 52%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[ 57%] ExtractingPackage
[ 60%] InspectingPackage
[ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[ 70%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
AMDeviceInstallApplication failed: -402620394
```

The solution deploys successfully to the iOS simulator - just not an real device/iPhone.

Comment: Are you sure its a Parse related problem instead of signing or certificate or provisioning problem?

Comment: It deploys fine to the iPhone if I don't have the parse config option checked, so not too sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your certificates and entitlements correctly per these instructions:
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#push

Then you'll need to specify your provisioning profile and certificates in your Trigger.io local config:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/local-config.html

If you still have problems, please contact support@trigger.io sending your config.json and local_config.json.

Comment: Thanks Amir! Works like a treat now.